# MySQL Multiple Table Joins incorrect summation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join and sum three tables together (MySQL), grouped by a 'tracking number' and an 'order_ID':

```
invoice_data_dhl
master_track_nums
payments
```

***Problem***: When they are multiple `payments` rows for an order_ID, it is multiplying the `DHL_COST` total by the number of results in the `payments` table for the order_ID.

```
SELECT 
invoice_data_dhl.Waybill_Number,
sum(invoice_data_dhl.AWB_Original_Amount) AS DHL_COST,
master_track_nums.order_ID,
sum(payments.revenue) AS REVENUE
FROM invoice_data_dhl
LEFT JOIN master_track_nums
ON invoice_data_dhl.Waybill_Number = master_track_nums.track
LEFT JOIN payments
ON master_track_nums.order_ID = payments.order_ID
GROUP BY invoice_data_dhl.Waybill_Number
```

Can this be written so that I can get the results with a single query that outputs the results like the below?

```
Waybill_Number  DHL_COST    order_ID    REVENUE
7022193792       182.52       110632      234
4536137201      3311.96       107637     4074
3927382187       248.95       110384      636
7812896712        74.85       106998      247
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: "Can this be written so that I can get the results with a single query that outputs the results like the below?," Yes.  You'll have to aggregate the results before doing the join.  Thus an inline query which returns the desired DHL_cost before the added join to payments cause the cost to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED: but something like this:  Updated: didn't remove sum on revenue in inline query.

```
SELECT A.waybill_number, A.DHL_COST, A.Order_ID, Sum(payments.Revenue)
FROM 
  (SELECT invoice_data_dhl.Waybill_Number,
     sum(invoice_data_dhl.AWB_Original_Amount) AS DHL_COST,
     master_track_nums.order_ID
   FROM invoice_data_dhl
   LEFT JOIN master_track_nums
       ON invoice_data_dhl.Waybill_Number = master_track_nums.track
   GROUP BY master_track_nums.Order_ID, invoice_data_dhl.Waybill_Number) A
LEFT JOIN payments
  ON A.order_ID = payments.order_ID
GROUP BY A.waybill_number, A.DHL_COST, A.Order_ID
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to add in the `GROUP BY` statement at the end:" GROUP BY A.Waybill_Number" (and match the capitalization in the first line).